# Unit testing React components that access a global store

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

First off, please let me know if this is not the right place to ask this question or move it to the right place.

I am starting to write unit tests for some React components. One of them does not have any props but depends on a `store`:

```
const PlayerSelector = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const divRef = useRef(null);
  const [{ playerList }, dispatch] = useStore();
...
```

where `userStore()` comes from:

```
export const StateContext = createContext(null);

export const StoreProvider = ({ initialState, reducer, children }) => (
  <StateContext.Provider
    value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}
  >
    {children}
  </StateContext.Provider>
);

export const useStore = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

My problem is that when I try to `render` `PlayerSelector` in the test file, I run into an error because the test does not have access to that store:

```
it('loads component', () => {
  const { queryByRole } = render(<PlayerSelector />);
  expect(queryByRole('button')).toHaveAttribute('aria-label');
});
```

The result is `TypeError: object null is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))` pointing to this line:

```
const [{ firmList }, dispatch] = useStore();
```

After googling a lot, I found some helpful resources indicating how to mock context - but not how to do the same for a reducer. I do not know if I am overcomplicating things and should probably find another way to test, or if I am missing an obvious answer. In any event, I would appreciate any tips or direction you can share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are testing a component that consumes a context from a provider you also need to render the provider in order to provide the context. The `render` takes a second options argument that can include a [wrapper](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#wrapper) to wrap the component being tested.

Example:

```
const customWrapper = ({ children }) => <SomeProvider>{children}</SomeProvider>;

it('loads component', () => {
  const { queryByRole } = render(
    <PlayerSelector />,
    {
      wrapper: customWrapper
    },
  );
  expect(queryByRole('button')).toHaveAttribute('aria-label');
});
```

With your redux-like provider you can create us an instance of your `StoreProvider` to create a wrapper for testing.

```
it('loads component', () => {
  const { queryByRole } = render(
    <PlayerSelector />,
    {
      wrapper: ({ children }) => (
        <StoreProvider
          initialState={{}} // <-- any initial state object
          reducer={rootReducerFunction} // <-- any reducer function
        >
          {children}
        </StoreProvider>
      ),
    },
  );
  expect(queryByRole('button')).toHaveAttribute('aria-label');
});
```

If you find yourself needing to write the wrapper utility a lot you can also create a [custom render function](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup#custom-render), which more or less duplicates the above.

```
const StateProvider = ({ children }) => (
  <StoreProvider
    initialState={{}} // <-- any initial state object
    reducer={rootReducerFunction} // <-- any reducer function
  >
    {children}
  </StoreProvider>
);

export const renderWithState = (ui, options) => {
  return render(ui, { wrapper: StateProvider, ...options });
}
```

test

```
import { renderWithState } from '../path/to/utils';

...

it('loads component', () => {
  const { queryByRole } = renderWithState(<PlayerSelector />);
  expect(queryByRole('button')).toHaveAttribute('aria-label');
});
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver! I implemented your suggestion and then mocked the initialState by importing a .js file with the contents of the store. Finally, I had to wrap the PlayerSelection component inside of a MemoryRouter. I want you to know that I really appreciate the time you took to reply to my question and point me in the right direction. Thank you SO much!